# Cannot use import statement outside a module when importing modules in a web worker

Tags: javascript, webpack, importerror, web-worker

I'm trying to import a module in a web worker that imports another module and getting the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
My web worker is importing scripts like this:

```
importScripts(
  './utils.js',
  './nn.js'
);
```

The error points to the second line with `'./utils.js'`, but its actual origin is the first line of `utils.js` which is the following:

```
import * as DG from 'datagrok-api/dg';
```

I tried setting `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, but it results in me being unable to compile my project with *Webpack* and produces other errors.

I also tried to create a worker with `new Worker('my.worker.js', {type: "module"})` so I can use `import` statements in it, but in this case I'm unable to post a message to the worker and not even getting any error. Also [module workers are not supported anywhere except for Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker).

I tried to manage web workers with *workerize-loader*, but it doesn't work with *Webpack 5* which I'm using.

So my question is: how can I import a module in a web worker that contains module imports?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know webpack does not process scripts imported using [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), meaning that if you want to use [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) you have to configure webpack to output a compiled version of your `utils.js` module.

But idk why would you bother using [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) if you are using webpack.

You can just write `import './utils.js'` inside your worker and webpack will bundle them together when building your worker script.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic import inside web worker to import modules works for me:

```js
// js/worker.js
(async () => {
  try {
    // Load multiple modules concurrently
    const [module1, module2, module3] = await Promise.all([
      import('./module1.js'),
      import('./module2.js'),
      import('./module3.js')
    ]);
    
    // Use the imported modules
    module1.hello(); // This will log: Hello from module1!
    module2.greet(); // This will log: Greetings from module2!
    module3.sayHi(); // This will log: Hi from module3!
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to load modules:", error);
  }
})();
```

```js
// main.js
var worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');
```

You can have a look at a working example: [timerWorker.js](https://github.com/iamsmkr/seesaw/blob/main/js/timerWorker.js) web worker.

If you're following the example, please note that I had to add `timer.js` which is utilizing `timerWorker.js` web worker as `module` type in html like so:

```html
<script src="js/timer.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

Hope this helps!