# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The URL 'constants.js' is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I am trying to use `constants.js` inside a web worker `worker.js` using `importScripts` but it is failing with the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': 
   The URL 'constants.js' is invalid.
```

Both the `constants.js` and `worker.js` are present on the same path. I have tried using `importScripts('./constants.js')` but it still fails.

This is how contrived example looks like:

**constants.js**

```js
export const WEEKDAYS = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"];
```

**worker.js**

```js
import {
    WEEKDAYS,
} from './constants.js';

export const myworker = () => {
    /* eslint-disable no-undef */
    if ('function' === typeof importScripts) {
        importScripts('./constants.js');
    }

    /* eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals */
    self.onmessage = function ({ data }) {
        const { command } = data;
        if (command === 'log') {
           postMessage(WEEKDAYS[0]);
        } 
    };
};

export class WebWorkerBuilder {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['(' + code + ')()']);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}
```

**Seesaw.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WebWorkerBuilder, myworker } from './worker';

const Seesaw = () => {
  const [worker, setWorker] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const worker = new WebWorkerBuilder(myworker);
    worker.onmessage = function ({ data }) {
      console.log(data);
    };

    setWorker(worker);

    return () => {
        worker.terminate();
    };
}, []);

  return (
    <></>
  );
}

export default Seesaw;
```

I need to use constants in many other files which is why it is important I maintain them at a single place. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `type` to `"module"` during `Worker` construction then use static `import` in the `Worker` script, or use dynamic `import()` in your current script, e.g., `new Worker("./path/to/script.js", {type: "module"})`.

Right you are using `export`, the `Worker` is not an Ecmascript Module that exports that word in a script when the `Worker` script is not set as an Ecmascript Module.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't follow. Are you suggesting we don't need `WebWorkerBuilder` I had to define as shown above and directly instantiate `Worker` like you suggest? And we don't even need `importScripts`? Please elaborate.

Comment: Basically you can't use static `import` and `importScripts()` in the same script. I don't know what React is doing here. I don't use React. You can still use dynamic `import()` in your script without errors being thrown, as long as that's the only issue with what you are encountering.

Comment: Well I have removed `importScripts` and defined worker like `const worker = new Worker('./timerWorker.js', {type: "module"})` and now i get error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".` and the script doesn't work at all

Comment: Then you need to make sure you are serving `'./constants.js'` with `text/javascript` content type header.

Comment: This is how I got it working in a plain old javascript project as per your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78213638/1879109. It is still an issue in a reactjs project though!